# Pi / python / telegram: is it possible to stream live webcam to telegram?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, streaming, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I've knocked up a vehicle security project project with a Pi, PIR sensor, GPS, camera, LTE modem and a telegram bot to control it all - works fine for:

- sending videos, photos
- recording on motion detection
- live stream to local LAN (using pistreaming from github)

What I'd really like to do is have a solution to be able to view the live stream over the intertubes without forwarding ports or connecting via vpn into the pi.

Is it possible to take the output from the camera and stream it to a telegram group? I thought maybe if I record to a 'file' and send the file to the group but I'm not sure of implementation ..

Has anyone done / tried anything similar?

thanks in advance!